# Is there a way to procedure results as a subquery?

Tags: stored-procedures, google-bigquery

The problem I am trying to tackle is to be able to call a procedure and run SQL commands on results (like select). Example.

Procedure

```sql
-- BQ_procedure
-- Arguments arg1 STRING, arg2 STRING, arg3 STRING, arg4 STRING
SELECT id,
    time,
    text
FROM `bigquery-public-data.hacker_news.comments`
WHERE text in ([arg1, arg2, arg3, arg4]);
```

Use the results of a procedure in a subquery.

```sql
SELECT id,
    time,
    FROM (
        CALL `my_project.my_dataset.BQ_procedure`(
            'stock',
            'overflow',
            'help',
            'me',
        )
    );
```

Is it possible?
Does it make sense?

Answer (score 0):

What you're asking for is normally called a Table-value function or parameterized view. There is no such capability in BigQuery right now.

But your query may be written as a regular view as far as I can see like:

```sql
CREATE VIEW yourView AS SELECT id,
    time,
    text
FROM `bigquery-public-data.hacker_news.comments`;

SELECT id,
    time,
FROM yourView where text in [
            'stock',
            'overflow',
            'help',
            'me' ]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your comment. My query is more complicated than this, just wanted to illustrate the format of the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can use table valued functions for this, which gives you a filtered table in the response, which can be used same as other tables.

https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/table-functions

Eg:

Table Creation Query:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE FUNCTION `test.filtered_table`(arg1: string, arg2: string, arg3: string, arg4: string) AS 

SELECT * from `base-table` where param1=arg1 and param2=arg2 ...
```

It can be used as :

```
select * from test.filtered_table(arg1, arg2, arg3, arg4) 
where Date(partition) = '2023-01-01'
```